# Rigify - restart/reset to initial/default state

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a generate rig by rigify

[image: initial state]

I can apply some animation and change custom properties, for example neck follow in the chest "bone"
[image: animation state]

I can delete the animation and restart the transforms with  Pose / Clear Pose Transform / All menu (or Alt+G, Alt+R, Alt+S to clear location, rotation and scale)

[image: restart part 1]

but I can't restart o reset to initial state the custom properties, for example neck follow in the chest "bone" don't change to inicial value.
[image: restar part error]

**How can I restore the initial configuration of all bones and controllers, values, visibility and other properties?**

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I don't think you can restore the initial state for these values. There no defaults for these.
If you're starting anew you could set a keyframe for all values at frame 0 or something. Then if you delete all keyframes at frame 0 you'll have the defaults.